# Using protocol to trigger a segue from a UIView inside a UIViewcontroller

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, delegates, protocols

CONFIGURATION:

-`UIviewController` embedded in `Navigationcontroller`.
-`UIviewController` has a `UIscrollview` as subview
-`UIscrollview` has some views where charts are created: each view containing a chart has its own .h and .m file and from this file I want trigger a segue to a tableview controller.
-A `Tableviewcontroller` was added in xcode and a segue from the `UIviewController` to the `TableViewcontroller` was created as well (`Xcode`)

-created a protocol in the `UIView` to have the segue pushed from there.

PROBLEM:

delegate always nil, segue method will never be called

UIVIEW .h file

```
@protocol UItoUIvcDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)triggerSegue;


@end

@interface CFfirstGraph : UIView <CPTPlotDataSource , CPTPieChartDelegate,UIActionSheetDelegate>

@property(weak, nonatomic) id <UItoUIvcDelegate> delegate;


@end
```

UIVIEW .m file (snippet)

```
-(void)pieChart:(CPTPieChart *)pieChart sliceWasSelectedAtRecordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
 {

     if (self.delegate == nil)
     {
         NSLog(@"nil");
     }
     [self.delegate triggerSegue];
}
```

UIVIEWCONTROLLER .h file

```
#import "CFfirstGraph.h"

@interface CFMainViewController : UIViewController <UItoUIvcDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>


@end
```

UIVIEWCONTROLLER .m file (snippet)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 1000);
    [self.view addSubview:self.scrollView];
    CFfirstGraph *click =[[CFfirstGraph alloc]init];
    click.delegate = self ;

}


-(void)triggerSegue

{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"detailedData" sender:self];
    NSLog(@"estoy aqui");
}
```

What am I doing wrong ? why the delegate is always nil ? I tried to add the method setDelegate but still no luck.

Thanks,
    dom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, after many hours of sweat I found the issue.

First...delegate = nil was not the main problem.

The real issue was the protocol method triggering the segue was never called.

If i create and initialize a CFfirstGraph object (or even property) it won't be related to the view created already in x-code, and this is the main issue.

On the other hand...if I "CTRL-drag" an outlet from the UIview to the CFMainViewController i will have a property that is exactly the one i need:

```
@interface CFMainViewController () <UIScrollViewDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet CFfirstGraph *FirstGraph;
```

Then i assign the delegate to self (CFMainViewController) in the viewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.FirstGraph.delegate = self ;

    }
```

and the delegate method "triggerSegue" will be executed being called from the UIVIEW.

Best Regards,
          dom

Answer (score 0):

Make `CFfirstGraph` as a strong property.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) CFfirstGraph * click;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.click =[[CFfirstGraph alloc]init];
    self.click.delegate = self ;


    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 1000);
    [self.view addSubview:self.scrollView];

}
```

Comment: nope, still nil, but thanks for answering. I tried to move the click and click.delegate lines in the viewDidAppear but it did not work either. I think the protocol is implemented correctly so the issue must hide somewhere between the scrollview and the subviews with the charts in it.

Comment: could u please send the source code to shamsutk87@gmail.com ?